# Determining what variable are being accessed by methods

Tags: debugging, clr, windbg, workflow-foundation-4

I'm creating a WF program using OutArgument. When I attempt to access the key on the Dictionary I get a KeyNotFoundException and the process terminates. I have created a process dump of the failure and the CLR thread-stack is below. I can see four locals on the Main methods frame.

How can I determine which local on the Main frame has the reference to the dictionary that was being accessed? Do I have to inspect all the locals or is it possible to determine from the frame above?

```
0:000> !clrstack -a
OS Thread Id: 0xf20 (0)
Child SP       IP Call Site
0032ebc8 7742019d [HelperMethodFrame: 0032ebc8] 
0032ec84 7123f326 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].get_Item(System.__Canon)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        key = <no data>
    LOCALS:
        <no data>
        <no data>

0032ec90 00210235 UserInArgument.Program.Main(System.String[])
    PARAMETERS:
        args (0x0032ecec) = 0x023823dc
    LOCALS:
        0x0032ece8 = 0x0244a8fc
        0x0032ece4 = 0x0248ba2c
        0x0032ece0 = 0x023824dc
        0x0032ecdc = 0x0244a8fc
        0x0032ecd8 = 0x02465fb8
```

Answer (score 0):

using the following process I was able to see the string that was being passed as the key to the Dictionary:

1 - dump stack of managed functions

```
003ced0c 7123f326 (MethodDesc 7053d6c8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].get_Item(System.__Canon))
003ced18 00200136 (MethodDesc 001837d8 +0xe6 UserInArgument.Program.Main(System.String[]))
```

2 - dump the IL of the Dictionary indexer

```
ilAddr = 012d2050
IL_0000: nop 
IL_0001: newobj UserInArgument.WorkflowInCode::.ctor
IL_0006: stloc.1 
IL_0007: ldloc.1 
IL_0008: ldstr "Dblk"
IL_000d: call class [System.Activities]System.Activities.InArgum甥휄Έ섛撮  횰Έ辋撩았ϯ਀::op_Implicit 
IL_0012: callvirt UserInArgument.WorkflowInCode::set_FirstName
IL_0017: nop 
IL_0018: ldloc.1 
IL_0019: ldstr "third sample"
IL_001e: call class [System.Activities]System.Activities.InArgum甥휄Έ섛撮  횰Έ辋撩았ϯ਀::op_Implicit 
IL_0023: callvirt UserInArgument.WorkflowInCode::set_SecondName
IL_0028: nop 
IL_0029: ldloc.1 
IL_002a: call System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker::Invoke 
IL_002f: pop 
IL_0030: newobj UserInArgument.Workflow::.ctor
IL_0035: call System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker::Invoke 
IL_003a: stloc.0 
IL_003b: ldloc.0 
IL_003c: ldstr "OutMessage_Should_Fail"
IL_0041: callvirt class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IDictio甥휄Έ섛撮  횰Έ辋撩았ϯ਀::get_Item 
IL_0046: call System.Console::WriteLine 
IL_004b: nop 
IL_004c: ret
```

The ldstr function pushes a new object reference to a string literal -> ldstr "OutMessage_Should_Fail".

Comment: This method does not work in all cases. For example I was not able to determine the string literal that was passed to a Console. Readline() function. Which I deliberately coded to cause a InvalidCastException.

Comment: What are all the strange UTF characters? Does it appear like that in your WinDbg?